# Update button on modal form not updating in MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I am displaying data on the ViewAllTasks page which has a delete, an edit and an add.  They all work except for the update one.  I do not get any errors and the program seems to run fine but the database does not get updated and the view is not updated as well.
The Add does something similar and it works:  it inserts a record in the database and the view is updated via the loadData() javascript.  What is it that I am doing wrong?  Please help.  Thank you

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
    //Load Data in Table when documents is ready
    $(document).ready(function () {
       loadData();
    });

    //Load Data function
```

```
function loadData() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Tickets/ListITTasks",
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {
            var html = '';
            $.each(result, function (key, item) {
                html += '<tr>';
                html += '<td>' + item.ITNumber + '</td>';
                html += '<td>' + item.ITDescription + '</td>';
                html += '<td>' + item.ITEnterDate + '</td>';
                html += '<td>' + item.ITAssignedTo + '</td>';
                html += '<td>' + item.ITEstimatedCompletion + '</td>';
                html += '<td>' + item.ITPriority + '</td>';
                html += '<td>' + item.ITFrom + '</td>';
                html += '<td>' + item.ITStatus + '</td>';
                html += '<td><a href="#" onclick="return getbyTicketNumber(' + item.ITNumber + ')">Edit</a> | <a href="#" onclick="DeleteItTask(' + item.ITNumber + ')">Delete</a></td>';
                html += '</tr>';
            });
            $('.tbody').html(html);
        },
        error: function (errormessage) {
            alert(errormessage.responseText);
        }
    });
}
```

```
function AddItTask() {
    var res = validate();
    if (res == false) {
        return false;
    }
    var taskObj = {
        ITDescription: $('#ITDescription').val(),
        ITEnterDate: $('#ITEnterDate').val(),
        ITAssignedTo: $('#ITAssignedTo').val(),
        ITEstimatedCompletion: $('#ITEstimatedCompletion').val(),
        ITPriority: $('#ITPriority').val(),
        ITFrom: $('#ITFrom').val(),
        ITStatus: $('#ITStatus').val()
    };
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST", 
        url: "/Tickets/AddTask",
        data: JSON.stringify(taskObj), 
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {
            loadData();
            //$('#myModal').modal('hide');
            clearTextBox();
        },
        error: function (errormessage) {
            alert(errormessage.responseText);
        }
    });       
}
```

```
    function getbyTicketNumber(TicketNumber) {
    $('#ITDescription').css('border-color', 'lightgrey');
    $('#ITEnterDate').css('border-color', 'lightgrey');
    $('#ITAssignedTo').css('border-color', 'lightgrey');
    $('#ITEstimatedCompletion').css('border-color', 'lightgrey');
    $('#ITPriority').css('border-color', 'lightgrey');
    $('#ITFrom').css('border-color', 'lightgrey');
    $('#ITStatus').css('border-color', 'lightgrey');
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Tickets/GetTaskByTicketNumber/" + TicketNumber,
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {
            $('#ITNumber').val(result.ITNumber);
            $('#ITDescription').val(result.ITDescription);
            $('#ITEnterDate').val(result.ITEnterDate);
            $('#ITAssignedTo').val(result.ITAssignedTo);
            $('#ITEstimatedCompletion').val(result.ITEstimatedCompletion);
            $('#ITPriority').val(result.ITPriority);
            $('#ITFrom').val(result.ITFrom);
            $('#ITStatus').val(result.ITStatus);

            $('#myModal').modal('show');
            $('#btnUpdate').show();
            $('#btnAddItTask').hide();
        },
        error: function (errormessage) {
            alert(errormessage.responseText);
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

```
function UpdateItTask() {
    var res = validate();
    if (res == false) {
        return false;
    }
    var taskObj = {
        Number: $('#ITNumber').val(),
        ITDescription: $('#ITDescription').val(),
        ITEnterDate: $('#ITEnterDate').val(),
        ITAssignedTo: $('#ITAssignedTo').val(),
        ITEstimatedCompletion: $('#ITEstimatedCompletion').val(),
        ITPriority: $('#ITPriority').val(),
        ITFrom: $('#ITFrom').val(),
        ITStatus: $('#ITStatus').val()
    };
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Tickets/UpdateTask",
        data: JSON.stringify(taskObj),
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {
            loadData();
            //clearTextBox();
            $('#myModal').modal('hide');
            $('#ITNumber').val("");
            $('#ITDescription').val("");
            $('#ITEnterDate').val("");
            $('#ITAssignedTo').val("");
            $('#ITEstimatedCompletion').val("");
            $('#ITPriority').val("");
            $('#ITFrom').val("");
            $('#ITStatus').val("");
        },
        error: function (errormessage) {
            alert(errormessage.responseText);
        }
    });
}
```

**VIEW:**

```
    @model IEnumerable<HelpDeskSupport.Models.ITTasksModel>

    @{
     Layout = null;
    }

    <!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>ViewAllTasks</title>

    <script src="~/Scripts/ITTasksJS.js"></script>
        </head>

        <div class="container">
    <h2>IT Tasks</h2>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" onclick="clearTextBox();">Add New Task</button><br /><br />

    <table class="display table table-striped table-bordered" id="tasksTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ITNumber)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ITDescription)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ITEnterDate)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ITAssignedTo)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ITEstimatedCompletion)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ITPriority)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ITFrom)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ITStatus)
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="tbody"></tbody>
    </table>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Add IT Task</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form>
                    <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="ITNumber">Number</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ITNumber" placeholder="Number" disabled="disabled" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="ITDescription">Description</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ITDescription" placeholder="Description" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="ITEnterDate">Enter Date</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ITEnterDate" placeholder="Enter Date" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="ITAssignedTo">Assigned To</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ITAssignedTo" placeholder="Assigned To" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="ITEstimatedCompletion">Estimated Completion</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ITEstimatedCompletion" placeholder="Estimated Completion" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="ITPriority">Priority</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ITPriority" placeholder="Priority" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="ITFrom">From</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ITFrom" placeholder="From" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="ITStat">Status</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ITStatus" placeholder="Status" />
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnAddItTask" onclick="return AddItTask();">Add</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnUpdate" style="display:none;" onclick="UpdateItTask();">Update</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CONTROLLER:**

```
    public ActionResult ViewAllTasks()
    {
        HelpDeskDBHandle dbhandle = new HelpDeskDBHandle();
        return View(dbhandle.GetITTasksList());
    }

    //ADD IT TASK
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult AddTask(ITTasksModel Task)
    {
        HelpDeskDBHandle hdDB = new HelpDeskDBHandle();          
        return Json(hdDB.AddTaskIT(Task), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    //LIST IT TASKS
    public JsonResult ListITTasks()
    {
        HelpDeskDBHandle hdDB = new HelpDeskDBHandle();
        return Json(hdDB.GetITTasksList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    public JsonResult GetTaskByTicketNumber(int id)
    {
        HelpDeskDBHandle hdDB = new HelpDeskDBHandle();
        var ITNumber = hdDB.GetITTasksList().Find(x => x.ITNumber.Equals(id));
        return Json(ITNumber, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    //UPDATE TASK
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult UpdateTask(ITTasksModel Task)
    {
        HelpDeskDBHandle hdDB = new HelpDeskDBHandle();
        return Json(hdDB.UpdateTaskIT(Task), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

**DATABASE HANDLE:**

```
    private void connection()
    {
        string constring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["HelpDeskSupportConn"].ToString();
        con = new SqlConnection(constring);
    }

    public List<ITTasksModel> GetITTasksList()
    {
        connection();
        List<ITTasksModel> Ittaskslist = new List<ITTasksModel>();

        string constring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["HelpDeskSupportConn"].ToString();
        string query = "SELECT * FROM ITTasks";
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query))
            {
                cmd.Connection = con;
                con.Open();
                using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (sdr.Read())
                    {
                        Ittaskslist.Add(new ITTasksModel
                        {
                            ITNumber = Convert.ToInt32(sdr["ITNumber"]),
                            ITDescription = Convert.ToString(sdr["ITDescription"]),
                            ITEnterDate = Convert.ToString(sdr["ITEnterDate"]),
                            ITAssignedTo = Convert.ToString(sdr["ITAssignedTo"]),
                            ITEstimatedCompletion = Convert.ToString(sdr["ITEstimatedCompletion"]),
                            ITPriority = Convert.ToString(sdr["ITPriority"]),
                            ITFrom = Convert.ToString(sdr["ITFrom"]),
                            ITStatus = Convert.ToString(sdr["ITStatus"])
                        });
                    }
                }
                con.Close();
            }
            return Ittaskslist;
        }
    }

    public int AddTaskIT(ITTasksModel itt)
    {
        int i;
        connection();

        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("p_AddITTicket", con);
        com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ITDescription", itt.ITDescription);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ITEnterDate", itt.ITEnterDate);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ITAssignedTo", itt.ITAssignedTo);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ITEstimatedCompletion", itt.ITEstimatedCompletion);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ITPriority", itt.ITPriority);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ITFrom", itt.ITFrom);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ITStatus", itt.ITStatus);

        con.Open();
        i = com.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        return i;
    }

    public int UpdateTaskIT(ITTasksModel itt)
    {
        int i;
        connection();
        con.Open();

        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("p_UpdateITTicket", con);
        com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ITNumber", itt.ITNumber);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ITDescription", itt.ITDescription);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ITEnterDate", itt.ITEnterDate);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ITAssignedTo", itt.ITAssignedTo);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ITEstimatedCompletion", itt.ITEstimatedCompletion);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ITPriority", itt.ITPriority);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ITFrom", itt.ITFrom);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ITStatus", itt.ITStatus);

        i = com.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();

        return i;
    }
```

**MODEL:**

```
    public class ITTasksModel
{
    [Key]
    public int ITNumber { get; set; }
    public string ITDescription { get; set; }
    public string ITEnterDate { get; set; }
    public string ITAssignedTo { get; set; }
    public string ITEstimatedCompletion { get; set; }
    public string ITPriority { get; set; }
    public string ITFrom { get; set; }
    public string ITStatus { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: There's *a lot* of code here for us to look through.  Can you narrow down the problem a bit?  Start with the button being clicked.  When you use your browser's debugger, does it invoke the intended function?  Are there any errors at all on the browser console?  Stepping through that function in the browser's debugger, do all of the variables have the values you expect? Is the AJAX request made?  Does the request have the data you expect? Debugging the server-side code, is the expected controller action invoked in that request? Does it receive the expected data? Basically, where does this fail?

Comment: Is the update passing the primary key that would be needed for your back end to identify which record it needs to update? Other than that, see comment above - check the browser console and see if any errors are shown there.

Comment: I see your ITNumber field is disabled. Often, disabled controls aren't passed in to the server and this may not be getting bound. Make it readonly instead and see how that goes.

Comment: I found the solution.

Comment: I had to substitute

Comment: This    ITNumber: $('#ITNum').val()    instead of     Number: $('#ITNum').val()

Comment: Thank you all for your input, highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution:

This
ITNumber: $('#ITNum').val()

Instead of
Number: $('#ITNum').val()